# Strong SSL with Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, ssl, aes

I'm trying to create a self signed certificate for use with Apache Tomcat 6.  Every certificate I can make always results in the browser connecting with AES-128.  The customer would like me to demonstrate that I can create a connection at AES-256.

I've tried java's keytool and openssl.  I've tried with a variety of parameters, but can't seem to specify anything about the keysize, just the signature size.

How can I get the browser-tomcat connection to use AES-256 with a self signed certificate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okie doke, I think I just figured this out.

As I said above, the key bit of knowledge is that the cert doesn't matter, so long as it's generated with an algorithm that supports AES 256-bit encryption (e.g., RSA).  Just to make sure that we're on the same page, for my testing, I generated my self-signed cert using the following:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

Now, you have to make sure that your Java implementation on your server supports AES-256, and this is the tricky bit.  I did my testing on an OS X (OS 10.5) box, and when I checked to see the list of ciphers that it supported by default, AES-256 was NOT on the list, which is why using that cert I generated above only was creating an AES-128 connection between my browser and Tomcat.  (Well, technically, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA was not on the list -- that's the cipher that you want, according to [this JDK 5 list](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#AppA).)

For completeness, here's the short Java app I created to check my box's supported ciphers:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class CipherSuites {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SSLSocketFactory sslsf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    String[] ciphers = sslsf.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    Arrays.sort(ciphers);
    for (String cipher : ciphers) {
      System.out.println(cipher);
    }
  }
}
```

It turns out that JDK 5, which is what this OS X box has installed by default, needs the "Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" installed in order to tell Java that it's OK to use the higher-bit encryption levels; you can [find those files here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index_jdk5.jsp) (scroll down and look at the top of the "Other Downloads" section).  I'm not sure offhand if JDK 6 needs the same thing done, but the same policy files for JDK 6 [are available here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp), so I assume it does.  Unzip that file, read the README to see how to install the files where they belong, and then check your supported ciphers again... I bet AES-256 is now on the list.

If it is, you should be golden; just restart Tomcat, connect to your SSL instance, and I bet you'll now see an AES-256 connection.

Comment: Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files must be installed in jdk home folder or just in tomcat/lib folder?

Comment: They need to be in your JDK's /lib/security subdirectory (e.g., $JAVA_HOME/lib/security). This information is in the README of the files linked above.

Answer (score 1):

danivo, so long as the server's cert is capable of AES encryption, the level of encryption between the browser and the server is independent of the cert itself -- that level of encryption is negotiated between the browser and server.  In other words, my understanding is that the cert doesn't specify the level of encryption, just the *type* of encryption (e.g., AES).  See [this link](http://www.trustico.com/material/techpaper_encryption.pdf) (PDF) for verification of this, and how the cert resellers upsell "256-bit-capable" certs despite the cert not being what determines 256-bit capability.

So you're just fine with the cert you have that supports AES-128 -- and they key is to figure out how to get Tomcat to support AES-256 (since most, if not all, major browsers certainly support it).

Answer (score 1):

The strength of the SSL connection is negotiated between the browser and the server (or whatever is providing SSL). It might be their browser asking for a weaker cypher. Have they ever seen a 256-AES SSL connection on this browser? AES-128 is still a very secure algorithm, so unless they have something that they want to protect from off line (think: supercomputer brute force generating 2^128 keys [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack)) attack, 128-bit should be fine. If they really need that much protection, they probably should be using a  more stable solution for data access than a website, a secure ssh tunnel to their server is bulletproof (you can tell them they can have their 256-bit AES and 4096-bit RSA too), or a vpn depending upon implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is 
http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-disable-weak-ciphers-and-ssl-2-in-tomcat.html 
and 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#AppA

Depending on whether you want good security and compatibility or PCI certification.